# How to get max value of nested array in array of objects (with an extra condition)

Tags: javascript

```
const highestFinish = Math.max(...team.flatMap(member => member.finishes));
const team = [
    { name: 'John Doe', finishes: ['105', '108'] },
    { name: 'Peter Pie', finishes: ['140'] }
]
```

This solution works for determing the highest value, but supposed I want to have a specific index inside the finishes array how would I get the max value give the index.
For example, if the index is 1, it should return 108, if the index is 0, it should return 140.
How can i change the given function to acheive this?

Answer (score 2):

You can `map` to the i-th element instead of `flatMap` and filter out `undefined`:

```js
const team = [
    { name: 'John Doe', finishes: ['105', '108'] },
    { name: 'Peter Pie', finishes: ['140'] }
]
const highestFinish = (i) => Math.max(...team.map(member => member.finishes[i]).filter(el => el !== undefined));

console.log(highestFinish(0));
console.log(highestFinish(1));
```